# Transparent Logo on the Object

Tags: materials, uv, transparency

Greetings dear 3D artists!
I am trying to place a png-logo on a coffee pot. Usually I use the diagram shown in Figure #1. For simple material, this scheme works as shown in Figure #2. For a more complex material (pale copper, Figure #3), the result of the work changes. The logo appears in unpredictable places. This is shown in Figure #4. UV unwrapping of faces for logo placement is shown in Figure #5. What can I do to get the logo to appear in one place? Changing the "Repeat" option to "Clip" has no results. Blender version 2.93.

[image]

Comment: well, the reason is that your new object is probably UV unwrapped as a whole, the solution would be to use a mapping node to use only UV that you want (and to make 2nd separated UV) or just take all the rest of the object UV and place it into transparent part of your image... But I would really recommend using mix RGB with this image as the factor with individual mapping node

Comment: I am using local UV-unwrapping. As shown in Figure #5. I only select the area for the logo placement. And the cup and the coffee pot are not related. They are from different files.

Comment: The coffee pot is one object. I used CTRL-J to merge the meshes. It has several slots with different materials.

Comment: even though you've only selected the logo area, the rest of the object will also unwrap, so as MikoCG says, you need to make sure that the rest of the UVs do not overlap with the logo in the UV Editor, select all these faces and scale them down so that they don't overlap

Comment: OK. Thanks! I fixed everything. I thought that if these surfaces are not visible then they do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UV-unwrapping contains the hidden surfaces of the object. This must be taken into account when doing local UV-unwrapping.